# About regex in Dreamweaver

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

How to replace this:

`<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/gallery_1(maybe 2 or 3, etc.).gif"><br>`

to this:

```
<a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/gallery_1(the same as the above).gif"><br></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<img src="\([^"]+\)"><br>
```

With

```
<a href="#"><img src="\1"><br></a>
```

As an aside, your `<a>` really should not contain a `<br>`. Better: Make it `display: block;` with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Find:

`(\<img src="[^"]+?"\>\<br\>)`

Replace:

`<a href="#">$1</a>`